# Sum of centered random variables with finite variance converges almost surely

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Given $X_i$ for $i \geq 1$ random variables with mean 0 and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{Var}(X_i)<\infty$
and their sum $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ I want to show that $S_n$ converges almost surely as $n \to \infty$ using the maximum difference between any two elements of $S_n$ is finite, using: $P\left(\max_{1 \leq k \leq r} |S_{n+k} - S_n| > \epsilon\right)$ Any hints?

Comment: What are you stuck exactly? Have you ever seen something that looks like [Kolmogorov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality)?

Comment: so I know that the Var($S_n$) is the sum of variances of  $X_i$, meaning it's finite. But not sure how to go from there...

Comment: This is false.  Take $X \sim N(0,1)$ and define $X_n=X/n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to prove that $(S_n)$ is almost surely a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) -- which will imply that $(S_n)$ converges almost surely, as your random variables are real-valued.

---

Consider $Z_n=\sup_{k,l\ge n} |S_k-S_l|$. We want to show that $Z_n\to 0$ almost surely. From [Kolmogorov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality),

$$\mathsf{P}(Z_n\ge \varepsilon)\le \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} \sum_{k\ge n} \mathsf{E} X_k^2.$$

Since $\sum_k \mathsf{E} X_k^2$ converges by assumption, for all $r\ge 1$ one can find $n_r\ge 1$ such that $\mathsf{P}(Z_{n_r}\ge 1/r)\le 1/r^2$. By [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Statement_of_lemma_for_probability_spaces), almost surely it holds that $Z_{n_r}<1/r$ for all but finitely many $r$. Finally $(Z_n)$ is nonincreasing, so that $Z_n\to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: The statement in the question is false in general (see my comment above).  Kolmogorov's inequality requires independence.

Comment: @Michael - Sure, we need independence.

Comment: I am a little confused here. All you showed is that the probability is bounded (of course all probabilites are bounded.) How did you get the stuff with the $r$?

Comment: @MathIsLife12: not sure I understand the comment. The RHS converges to 0 as $n\to \infty$

Comment: @md5 oh I get it. Thanks.